# -2.6 to the power of 0.2 outputs #IND00

Tags: c, pow, negative-number

currently i'm doing my practice for C language and i've found one question about function pow() in C\C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    double k = 0.2;
    printf("2.6^k = %f\n", pow(2.6, k));
    printf("-2.6^k = %f\n", pow(-2.6, k));

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2.6^k = 1.210583
-2.6^k = -1.#IND00
```

In this example -2.6 to the power of 0.2 i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶l̶e̶x̶ ̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶(Edit: it is),but output says(as i think) that number is indeterminable.

And in my practice there is the following:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOsXv.png)

I implemented this like that:

```
/* e = 2.1783; x = -2.6 */
result = pow(cos(pow(x,0.2) - pow(e,-x + sqrt(3))) + 1.61,2);
```

But due to (-x + sqrt(3)) being negative number it outputs:

-1.#IND00

Comment: What number did you expect from `-2.6^0.2` and why? This is probably a mistake in the exerice you were given. Also, for `e^??` you should be using `exp(??)`.

Comment: it is complex, my bad

Comment: -2.6^0.2 has a real value of -1,21, and 4 other (complex) values. It is the 5th root of -2.6. But there is an answer that explains that with a rounding error it will be complex.

Comment: never use `pow(e, x)`, always use `exp(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 0.2 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.  So what you have is not actually 0.2 but a value slightly *more* than that.  This yields a complex result so `pow` returns NaN.

Reading into this further, section 7.12.7.4 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `pow` function states:

> ```
> double pow(double x, double y);
> ```
>
> A domain error occurs if `x` is finite
> and negative and `y` is finite and not an integer value.

In the event of a domain error, an implementation-defined value is returned.  While MSVC doesn't seem to document what it does in this case, it apparently returns NaN.  In the case of Linux, the man pages explicitly state that NaN is returned in this case.

Answer (score 1):

With complex number math, -2.6<sup>0.2</sup> is 0.979382 +0.711563*i.

`pow(-2.6, k)` does not have a *real* answer.

Alternative: use complex math:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  double k = 0.2;
  printf("2.6^k = %f\n", pow(2.6, k));
  complex double y = cpow(-2.6, k);
  printf("-2.6^k = %f %f*i\n", creal(y), cimag(y));
}
```

Output

```
2.6^k = 1.210583
-2.6^k = 0.979382 0.711563*i
```

Comment: thanks a lot. as it turned out @HolyBlackCat was right, that was just a mistake in the given exercise